# Upper Bound on Probability of Maximum Statistic from Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be I.I.D. Exponential$(\lambda)$. Let $X_{(n)}$ denote the maximum ordered statistic.
Prove that $$P\left(X_{(n)}\geq \frac{2\log(n)}{\lambda}\right)\leq\frac{1}{n}.$$
Work so far:
$$
\begin{align} 
P\left(X_{(n)}\geq\frac{2\log(n)}{\lambda}\right)&=1-F_{X_{(n)}}\left(\frac{2\log(n)}{\lambda}\right)\\&=1-\left[F_X\left(\frac{2\log(n)}{\lambda}\right)\right]^n\\&=1-\left[1-\text{exp}\{-2\log(n)\}\right]^n\\&=1-\left[1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right]^n
\end{align} 
$$
From here, I can't think of a clever way to change the RHS to be less than or equal to $\frac{1}{n}$. Any hints or tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried series expansion?

Comment: Let me give this a try, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: [Bernoulli’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality?wprov=sfti1):

> $$(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx\quad x\geq -1, n\in\mathbb N.$$

Comment: Excellent hint! I think I solved it using the alternative inequality $(1+x)^r\leq e^{rx}$ for $r>0$ and real number x

Comment: Knowing $(1+x)^{n}\leq e^{xn}$ isn’t much use, You get $$1-(1-1/{n^2})^{n}\geq 1-e^{-1/n}.$$ The inequality is in the wrong direction. @Jeff If $a\leq b,$ then $1-a\geq 1-b.$

Comment: Your inequality gets you a lower bound for the probability, though, $\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}.$ @Jeff